# How do I toggle the planetary scan overlays?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I put a satellite in polar orbit and used the big scanner to scan the planet (technically a moon) for ore.

[image: Scanning Minmus]

Now I have a green overlay on the planet making it difficult to determine landing location. Is there any way to toggle this on and off?

[image: Ore scan overlay]

How can I land here? Minmus, where are your plains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out you can right click the Survey Scanner part to toggle the overlay on or off. You can also do other cool things with it.

[image: Ksp overlay toggle]